# Display label and <a> same line inside a table

Tags: html

```
"<td style=max-width:0px;>" +
                    "<span> Issuer: <a href=/app?"+JSON.stringify(issuer)+" target='_blank'>  <span> " + celldata[rowIndex].hiddenprops.issuer +" </span></a> </span>"+
                "</td>"
```

The result should be: "issuer: rojioijoijrieroirjg" 
but I get
: "issuer:
   rojioioijoij"

on two different lines. I tried display:inline on every tag and tried to insert tags and stuff but nothing is working?

Any idea how I should proceed. All I want is a label on the same line than my link inside a `<td>`

Comment: Would you please at least get your code easier to read before asking someone to help?

Comment: Is table-layout is fixed ?

Comment: no it's not I used max-width:0px to have the same effect

Comment: That embedded style is invalid.It is equivalent to writing `style=max-width:0px;` when what you need is `style='max-width:0px;'` - notice the enclosing quotes on the text of the style.

Comment: ok so this is the reason ? also it may be invalid but this css prop is working how does it come ? thks